# Problems converting Keys in keypad to an AutoHotKey Script

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, keypad

I am trying to write a basic ahk script to convert some hotkeys in a game from {'F1' 'F2' 'f3'and Esc} to num1 num2 num3 and num enter. <-- the keys on the Keypad on the right of my keyboard.

**Issue**

The ahk script does not recognize these values as keys in my number pad.
(the spot on the right side of keyboard that has values from 1-9 in a 3 x 3. I am having trouble finding what to enter for my Num/Keypad values in the script.

This is what I currently have...

`Num Enter::Escape`
`Num 1::F1`
`Num 2::F5`
`Num 3::F6`
`Num 8::up`
`Num 6::right`
`Num 5::down`
`Num 4::left`
`Ctrl::suspend`  <----It does not recognize "Num" as a key

And this is the message that I get after I try to run the script via AutoHotKey

> Error at line 1.
> Line Text: Num Enter:: Escape
> Error;Invalid Hotkey
> The program will now exit

**My Question**

What text should I enter to trasnfer the original hotkeys (<kbd>F1</kbd> <kbd>F2</kbd> <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> to Number pad <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> <kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> <-- the Enter on the number pad not the one on your main keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put **num*** like:

```
Numlock ON      Numlock OFF
Numpad0         NumpadIns
Numpad1         NumpadEnd
Numpad2         NumpadDown
Numpad3         NumpadPgDn
Numpad4         NumpadLeft
Numpad5         NumpadClear
Numpad6         NumpadRight
Numpad7         NumpadHome
Numpad8         NumpadUp
Numpad9         NumpadPgUp
NumpadDot (.)   NumpadDel
NumpadDiv (/)   NumpadDiv (/)
NumpadMult (*)  NumpadMult (*)
NumpadAdd (+)   NumpadAdd (+)
NumpadSub (-)   NumpadSub (-)
NumpadEnter     NumpadEnter
```

You have all the information on [List of Keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)